# BackBlazeTokenResponse - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "allowed"

Tags: json, api, upload, jackson-databind

I am getting an error while trying to get an BackBlaze Authorization token. It was working fine before, and suddenly I started getting this error message -

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "allowed" (class au.com.polonious.cloud.node.backblaze.BackBlazeTokenResponse), not marked as ignorable (7 known properties: "authorizationToken", "minimumPartSize", "apiUrl", "downloadUrl", "accountId", "absoluteMinimumPartSize", "recommendedPartSize"])
 at [Source: {
  "absoluteMinimumPartSize": 5000000,
  "accountId": "b0c893f558bc",
  "allowed": {
    "bucketId": null,
    "capabilities": [
      "all"
    ],
    "namePrefix": null
  },
  "apiUrl": "https://api001.backblazeb2.com",
  "authorizationToken": "4_001b0c893f558bc0000000000_01851d94_6e8e3e_acct_yxmSYWYVETByLq8bwW8HMQSEjlM=",
  "downloadUrl": "https://f001.backblazeb2.com",
  "minimumPartSize": 100000000,
  "recommendedPartSize": 100000000
}
; line: 4, column: 15] (through reference chain: au.com.polonious.cloud.node.backblaze.BackBlazeTokenResponse["allowed"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:834)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1093)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1489)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1467)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:282)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2858)
```

Here is my code-

```
private BackBlazeTokenResponse getBackBlazeAuth(String accountId, String applicationKey) 
    throws Exception{
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String headerForAuthorizeAccount = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((accountId + ":" + applicationKey).getBytes());
    log.info("getBackBlaze Auth - headerForAuthorizeAccount - "+headerForAuthorizeAccount);
    BackBlazeTokenResponse backBlazeTokenResponse = new BackBlazeTokenResponse();
    String tokenJson="";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v1/b2_authorize_account");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", headerForAuthorizeAccount);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());    
        tokenJson = myInputStreamReader(in); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
      //log.info("Output JSON:"+tokenJson);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //JSON from file to Object
        log.info("tokenJson- "+ tokenJson);
        backBlazeTokenResponse = mapper.readValue(tokenJson, BackBlazeTokenResponse.class);
        log.info("getAuthorizationToken:"+backBlazeTokenResponse.getAuthorizationToken());


        return backBlazeTokenResponse;
    }
}
```

The error is in this line -

```
backBlazeTokenResponse = mapper.readValue(tokenJson, BackBlazeTokenResponse.class);
```

Not sure why it suddenly started throwing this error, probably something was changed in BackBlaze API. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This has solved my issue

```
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.setVisibilityChecker(VisibilityChecker.Std.defaultInstance().withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));
```